# MYSQL "SHOW TABLES FROM"

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database there are tables below:

```
temp;
2012;
2013;
2014;
2015;
```

I'd like to list the tables except `temp`
It should be something like

```
show tables from database like ...;
```

I also tried the operator `NOT`

But I failed. Can anyone help me for a correct SQL command?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, MS SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: I'm using MYSQL 
@MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Then juergen's answer below will be suitable.

Answer (score 3):

```
select table_schema
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema <> 'temp'
```